# Replace backslashes with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string

```
string s = "<textarea>\r\n</textarea>";
```

And I want to replace the textarea content dynamically, trying it like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(<textarea.*?>)(.*)(</textarea>)");
string a = regex.Replace(s, "$1new value$3");
```

Yet this does not procedure the output I want, which should be: `<textarea>new value</textarea>`. It just produces

```
<textarea>
</textarea>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It appears to be an XML string that you're trying to work with - consider using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` as those classes are specifically designed for it.

Comment: As @LB2 said, anyone looking to parse an XML-type string should see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`RegexOptions.SingleLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions) mode. Otherwise `.` does not match newlines.

According to the documentation:

> **Singleline**    Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot
>   (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except
>   \n).

Answer (score 3):

`.*` will stop when it encounters a `\n`.

So use `RegexOptions.MultiLine` option.

Or just change your regex to:

```
(?m)(<textarea.*?>)(.*)(</textarea>)
```

`(?m)` is inline multiline modifier.

### Edit:

Sorry It should've been `RegexOptions.SingleLine`. I was confused since I use regex only in javascript on a large basis.

Comment: Tried using `Regex regex = new Regex("(<textarea.*?>)(.*)(</textarea>)", RegexOptions.Multiline);` still does not give the desired result... Note: the string is `\r\n` and not `\\r\\n`

Comment: @user3182508 I think Amit got the check backwards, should be `SingleLine`.